# .wine-pipelight folder not present

Tags: 14.04, wine, firefox, pipelight

Following the instructions on the [pipelight installation page](http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html), I installed pipelight on Ubuntu 14.04. However, upon opening firefox the `.wine-pipelight` folder isn't present in my home folder, and I get the following errors:

```
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] attached to process.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] checking environment variable PIPELIGHT_SILVERLIGHT5_1_CONFIG.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] searching for config file pipelight-silverlight5.1.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:unknown] trying to load config file from '/home/alden/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1'.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] basicplugin.c:427:checkSilverlightGraphicDriver(): error in execlp command - probably silverlightGraphicDriverCheck not found or missing execute permission.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] basicplugin.c:441:checkSilverlightGraphicDriver(): GPU driver check - Your driver is not in the whitelist, hardware acceleration disabled.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] using wine prefix directory /home/alden/.wine-pipelight.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] checking plugin installation - this might take some time.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] basicplugin.c:374:checkPluginInstallation(): error in execvp command - probably dependencyInstaller/sandbox not found or missing execute permission.
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] basicplugin.c:384:checkPluginInstallation(): Plugin installer did not run correctly (exitcode = 1).
[PIPELIGHT:LIN:silverlight5.1] basicplugin.c:108:attach(): plugin not correctly installed - aborting.
```

I've reinstalled quite a few times and ran through many of the common fixes offered on the pipelight Launchpad pages and here on AskUbunta and still it fails to run.

Is there a reason why this folder isn't present, or why I'm getting these errors?

**Edit:** Oddly enough, the `.wine-pipelight` folder is created wtih I open [Nitro](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nitro/), although this still doesn't fix the issue.

**Edit II:** The [Pipelight Diagnostic Tool](http://fds-team.de/pipelight/) tells me there are three things wrong. It says I fail the Silverlight check (meaning websites will think I don't have Silverlight installed), the dllPath/dllname check (which I've checked to make sure leads to a valid file), and the attempt to load /etc/issue (which is definitely present).

Here's a picture of the errors:
[image]

And I've uploaded my config file (`/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.1`) which should be default: http://pastebin.com/PZa2YB1w

Answer (score 0):

Your debug output shows that Pipelight loads the configuration from `/home/alden/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1`. This config file is most probably corrupt and contains some invalid paths leading to the errors you encounter.

I would recommend to delete the file:

```
    rm /home/alden/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1
```

Pipelight should now fallback to its default configuration which is sufficient in most of the cases. If you still need to change something, you should copy the original config file from `/usr/share/pipelight/configs/pipelight-silverlight5.1` to `/home/alden/.config/pipelight-silverlight5.1` and check after each modification if it still works.

Comment: That doesn't fix it, although I just remembered to post the output of the [pipelight diagnostic tool](http://fds-team.de/pipelight/) which may help.